# How can I set a Foreign Key to the default through in Django?

Tags: python, django, model, foreign-keys

I want to set a foreign key to a many to many relationship without having to specify a *through* field or (specify it without affecting existing logic).

**monitor.py**

```
class QuoteMonitor(g.UserModel):
    quote_services = m. OneToOneField(g.QuoteService)
```

**quote.py**

```
class Quote(g.UserModel):
    name = m.CharField(max_length=512, default='New Quote')
    services = m.ManyToManyField(g.Service, blank=True)

class Service(g.UserModel):
    name = m.CharField(max_length=512, default='New Service')
```

I can't do this right now because *g.QuoteService* model doesn't exist. That table is automatically created by django many-to-many field.

Is it possible?

**Edit:**

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24686658/how-can-i-use-the-automatically-created-implicit-through-model-class-in-django-i) provides a similar answer.

Comment: Your description is extremely confusing. What do you mean `set a foreign key to many to many relationship`?  What's the relationship between `Quote` and `QuoteMonitor`? What is `g.QuoteService`? What is `g.Service`?

Comment: I mean exactly that. Im showing an example of what I want to achieve in "monitor.py" a relationship to a foreign key model that doesn't exist in "quote.py". QuoteService is the relationship between Quote and Service models. QuoteMonitor is the model I want to relate to this relationship.

Answer (score 2):

You can create an unmanaged model for the many-to-many relationship that django automatically creates.

```
class QuoteService(models.Model):
    quote = m.ForeignKey(g.Quote)
    service = m.ForeignKey(g.Service)

    class meta:
        db_table = 'table-name-goes-here'
        managed = False
```

Then you can create a model that references the m2m relationship via ForeignKey or 1-1 field:

```
class QuoteMonitor(g.UserModel):
    quote_service = m.OneToOneField(g.QuoteService)
```

Note: You should create QuoteMonitor in a 2nd migration, after your initial models have been created.

Comment: Thanks, this is useful to me. The initial models are already created so there's no problem with that.