# Django, listing the query-set of connected Models

Tags: django

I would like to list all conversations of a User. As seen from picture below, Conversation Model is not Directly connected to the User table. This is a freelancer site project, where users can register as workers to do jobs posted by users.

The result I want is:

```
my_conversations = User.Conversation.all()
```

I'm adding this picture, since it paints everything that I will summarise below.[image]

Let's images I have 2 users, one of which is a registered worker. Then it looks as follows:

```
**Users**
id   Name   ...
1    John
2    Bob

**Worker**
id   user_id   ...
1    2
```

John posted some job. We add 1 new entry to the `JOB` table.

```
**Job**
id    title                          user_id
1     Help me design a database      1
```

This is a M-to-M relationship (worker can apply for many jobs and one job can have many workers), we define a new table where `job_has_worker`.

For each `job_has_worker`, there should be a way to communicate between worker and job poster.

Now what I would like Django to do is load all conversations the user who is logged in e.g. load a list of my conversations for the jobs I posted.

**Views - My Posted Jobs**

```
User = request.user
Jobs = User.job_set.all()
```

**Views - My Conversations, *This is what I need***

```
User = request.user
Jobs = User.job_set.all()
for job in Jobs:
    # load conversations
    converstation = job.converstation_set.all()
    # also somehow append this to all conversations
```

**Views - Messages**
First I need to get conversation id

```
Messages = Conversation.get(pk=pk).message_set.get_all()
```

I'm going to add some security with if loops e.g.

```
if request.user.id not in message.sender || message.receiver
   return false
```

EDIT:

---

**Models.py**

```
class Worker(models.Model):
     user = OneToOneField(User)

class Conversation(models.Model):
     #What to here?
     #Job_Has_Worker = ForeignKey(Job, Worker)

class Message(models.Model):
     body = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=False)
     sender = models.IntegerField()
     receiver = models.IntegerField()
     conversation = models.ForeignKey(Conversation)

class Job(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=False)
    workers = models.ManyToManyField(Worker)
```

Comment: What do your models look like? This should be straightforward, Django can follow related fields in filters using `__` notation, but the precise details depend on how you've named the `ForeignKey` and `ManyToManyField`s on your models.

Comment: @PeterDeGlopper `Job` Model has a Foreign key (person who posted) `user = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', on_delete=models.CASCADE)` and also many-to-many with worker model. `workers = models.ManyToManyField(Worker)`. I'm not sure what the `Conversation` model connects to... since `Job_Has_Worker` doesn't exist in my Models.

Comment: Can you edit the relevant parts of the models into the question? Comment formatting makes code hard to read. And `Conversation` must have some kind of relation field - `Job_Has_Worker` could be an intermediate m2m table, Django creates those as needed to implement m2m fields.

Comment: @PeterDeGlopper I've added models.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without the relationship fields that involve `Conversation` I can't completely answer this, but here's an example using `Job`:

```
# All jobs for a given user:
Jobs.objects.filter(workers__user=request.user)
```

Your listed example of `User.job_set.all()` won't work, `User` doesn't have a direct relation to `Job` so it won't have a `job_set` attribute.

Assume `Conversation` is declared using a ForeignKey on the job/worker m2m implicit `through` model:

```
class Conversation(models.Model):
    job_worker = ForeignKey(Job.workers.through)
```

(Credit to [How can I use the automatically created implicit through model class in Django in a ForeignKey field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24686658/how-can-i-use-the-automatically-created-implicit-through-model-class-in-django-i) for the syntax to reference the implicit `through` model.)

Then something like this should work to get conversations:

```
Conversation.objects.filter(job_worker__worker__user=request.user).distinct()
```

Or this to get messages:

```
Messages.objects.filter(conversation__job_worker__worker__user=request.user).distinct()
```

You can use the `through` argument to your `ManyToManyField` to get a nicer name for the intermediate model than `Job.workers.through`, of course.

You can also walk back from an instance, as you were heading towards with `user.job_set.all()` - it would have to be `user.worker.job_set.all()` to start, and you'd want to check to ensure that the `user` has a non-empty `worker` first, but because `job_set` is itself a manager that returns querysets of `job`s that's a bit more cumbersome to work with for this indirect a relation. `some_worker.job_set.filter(...)` is clearer than `Job.objects.filter(worker=some_worker, ...)`, though, so it depends on the circumstances.

Comment: Thanks, I will work through this now. Just immediate observation, maybe I should remove the ManyToMany relationship and Manually create `Job_Worker` model with `worker_id`,`job_id` fields? Then I will be able to add a Foreign Key into `Conversation`, namely, `job_worker = ForeignKey(Job_Worker)`

Comment: I would also like to add REST API, in which case, I'm going to have to define the model (this `through` model) anyway?

Comment: I would leave it as a `ManyToMany`, if that's really the relationship structure the entities have, and just use the override arguments like `through` and if you like `db_table` when defining the relationship. You can explicitly declare the model if you like - I will be very surprised if the REST framework requires that, but it's entirely normal if you need information other than the relationships tracked. The docs are pretty good here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships

Comment: To be clear, I don't think you need to explicitly declare the `through` model to do what you need, but it's fine to do so if you find that easier to work with and will be required if you need fields like a join date tracked on the job/worker pairs.

Comment: Thank you! I guess we will cross that bridge when we get there (regarding REST) :)